# Navigating between months on jquery datepicker via external buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have to add extra functionality to a jQuery UI Datepicker's titlebar. The easiest way seems to be creating a separate external titlebar, and use it to control the datepicker's month stepper function with external buttons (while hiding the original titlebar).

Currently I can only do it by changing the date, but I want to be able to step to the next month without actually changing the date, just like DatePicker's built in month stepper buttons:

current html:

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
<br/>
<button id="prev">Previous Month</button>&nbsp;
<button id="next">Next month</button>
```

current js:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker();

$('#next, #prev').on('click', function(e) {
    var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
    e.target.id == 'next' ? date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+1) : date.setMonth(date.getMonth()-1);
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', date );
});
```

Is there a better way to step months externally?

http://jsfiddle.net/KFbZy/1/

Comment: Is not the default usage of the right/left arrows in the top of the datepicker? What is your need?

Comment: Yes, but I have to add some extra functionality to the top title bar. I have to make it able to be able to toggle (display/hide) the calendar part. Show the full date, and use the right/left arrows to step only one day while the calendar part is closed. Then when the date is clicked I have to open the calendar part.

Comment: Closed state:
[image](http://i.imgur.com/kyMq86F.jpg).
Open state (normal datepicker functionality):
[image](http://i.imgur.com/uiehhxS.jpg).

Sorry didn't figure out how to include an image url

Comment: Are an inline calendar? Can the provided answer fit your needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the standard usage of the datepicker the right-left arrows at the top of the datepicker allows you to go to the next-prev month.

But if you want to fire the next-prev month you can trigger a click on the standard buttons, so the behaviour will be same of the default funcionality.

Code:

```
$('#next, #prev').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.ui-datepicker-'+e.target.id).trigger("click");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/5Dcg3/

Comment: would have never thought about solving it this way! how simple :) thanks again!